# Trying to copy the pointer to a list, getting "cannot convert ... to ... in initialization" error

Tags: c++, list, pointers, static

I want my Bullet class to have access to a list of Ship, so I have a static variable that is a pointer to the list object.

```
class Bullet {
    ...
    static list<Ship*>* enemyList;
    ...
}
```

Declaring the list,

```
std::list<Ship*> enemyList;
```

Finally, I provide the definition for my static variable:

```
std::list<Ship*>* Bullet::enemyList = &enemyList;
```

However, the compiler gives the following error:

```
error: cannot convert `std::list<Ship*, std::allocator<Ship*> >**' to `std::list<Ship*, std::allocator<Ship*> >*' in initialization|
```

By changing my definition to the following, the program compiles but segfaults when the function requiring the list is called:

```
std::list<Ship*>* Bullet::enemyList = enemyList;  //no &
```

Which leads me to believe that there is an error in my understanding and usage of std::list, but I'm not sure what that is. Thanks!

**EDIT : Resolved**

As pointed out by Matt McNabb below, enemyList on the right hand side of

```
std::list<Ship*>* Bullet::enemyList = &enemyList;
```

referenced the enemyList on the left hand side rather than the enemyList I wanted to call outside of the class. Using distinct names solved this issue.

Comment: Any reason why you need a pointer etc. at all?

Comment: And you´re probably refering to the wrong enemyList. Just use a single list...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it sounds like you want:

```
static list<Ship> enemyList;
```

It's not clear why you want pointers to be involved.  If you use this form then all your other questions are rendered moot, but to answer it anyway:

This line makes no sense:

```
std::list<Ship*>* Bullet::enemyList = &enemyList;
```

You're trying to initialize the list to point to itself, which is not possible (since the list contains `Ship*`, not `list<Ship*>`).  The declaration would be:

```
list<Ship*> *Bullet::enemyList;
```

and you would also have to make that pointer point somewhere (by default it will be a null pointer).

Your second version compiles but it is just like writing:

```
int x = x;
```

hopefully you can understand why this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response! As a test, I renamed std::list<Ship*> enemyList; to "zenemyList" and that fixed up all the issues. I thought by not including Bullet:: in the assignment that it would choose to go with the list not in the class, but it turns out I was wrong!

Comment: @user3404452 The definition has to have the class name:: in it; if you don't then it's defining a different variable